# String interpolation trouble with Haml and Spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, spree

I'm trying to convert my Spree store to Haml, and I'm facing some trouble with some parts of the backend.
For instance, I take the following Haml code:

```
- @orders.each do |order|   
  %tr{:class => "state-#{order.state.downcase} #{cycle('odd', 'even')}"}   
  %tr{:class => "state-#{order.state.downcase}"}
```

And here's the output HTML (simplified to a single iteration):

```
<tr class="state-#order.state.downcase"></tr>
<tr></tr>
```

Can someone help me understand why the string interpolation is wrong in both cases? I have been looking at this for hours...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just revisited this and came across the fact that Deface (used by Spree) is not compatible with Haml.

So either one uses ERB and lives with it, or completely disables Deface and rewrite all 'defaced' views.

P.S.: In order to disable Deface, I added `config.deface.enabled = false` to `development.rb`, `production.rb` and `test.rb` inside `config/environments/`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `HAML` syntax looks fine, but it's possible `cycle` is causing trouble and failing silently.  Cycle is a RAILs method within `ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper`, so perhaps your code no longer is including that library now that you've dropped `Spree`.

If this is the source of the problem, you could either include the ActionView Helpers or rewrite your code without `cycle` with something like the following:

```
%table
  %tbody
    - @orders.each_with_index do |order,index|   
      %tr{:class => "state-#{order.state.downcase} #{%w(even odd)[index%2]}"}   
        %td{:class => "state-#{order.state.downcase}"}
          #{order.state}
```

PS - I'm assuming the second `tr` in your sample code is supposed to be a `td` and that you're just providing a fragment of the table.

Comment: Hi @Cam. I have tried with the modification you have suggested, but I'm getting the same result. I have put both those `%tr` to show how awkward the result is. In the first case, the `"#{}"` is essentially not treated as a string interpolation, and in the second case, the `class` attribute comes empty. I have tried with proper markup, i.e., `%table`, `%tr` and `%td`. But I was trying to isolate the problem. Anyway, that shouldn't change the way the Haml gets converted, but just the way the browser will render the content. Right?

Comment: The specific tag name shouldn't affect interpolation, so something else must be the matter here.  What do you see if you replace both `%tr`s with: `%p{:class => order.state.downcase}= order.state`?

Comment: This is what comes out: `<p class="complete">complete</p>`.

Comment: Interesting.  Seems it's able to access `order.state`, which is positive.  How about: `%p{:class => "state-%s" % order.state.downcase}= order.state`?  And if that works, you could then try: `%tr{:class => "state-%s %s" % [order.state.downcase, cycle('odd', 'even')]}"}`

Comment: Hmmm.. It did not work: `<p>complete</p>`. As for your second suggestion, I suppose you meant: `%tr{:class => "state-%s %s" % [order.state.downcase, cycle('odd', 'even')]}` (last `}"` was superfluous, although no error was reported!!--which is also weird, heh??). All I got was: `<tr></tr>`

Comment: Strange behavior; `haml` does handle interpolation on its own, so perhaps try reinstalling the `gem` or opening a ticket, mentioning the version of `Ruby` and `haml` you're working with. https://github.com/haml/haml